# jQuery cookie CORS doesnt work even with headers set and withCredentials

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, cookies

Application is on 'http://192.168.1.5:8000', and API server is on 'http://192.168.1.5:9000'. I'm trying to send GET requests with cookies to API server in the application using jQuery.

Here is the complete request headers (extracted from FireBug):

```
GET /api/rooms HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.5:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://192.168.1.5:8000
Origin: http://192.168.1.5:8000
Cookie: COOKIE=bf27f9f2-6bf8-4688-ac03-fc802653ce22
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Allow: GET, OPTIONS, POST
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control
Date: Wed, 09 Dec 2015 15:33:50 GMT
Content-Length: 6670
```

jQuery code:

```
$.ajax('http://192.168.1.5:9000/api', {
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

While browser got the response (with status code 200), but jQuery stops because of cross origin policy.

How to resolve this issue? More headers needed?

Answer (score 0):

Note, your response headers above use the wildcard * for the allow origin header,

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

yet the CORS spec indicates that wildcards may not be used for that header, for requests that support credentials (use the explicit origin value as the accept origin value instead).  CF: https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-requests

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "the actual explicit origin"

I hope that info helps,
..Mike Burati